# iOS App Metadata Rejected? Anything to Check in ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, app-store, admob

So I just got an app's metadata rejected. Their message:

```
Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves third-party advertisements. However, we were unable to locate ads in your app. 

Please reply to this message to provide the steps for locating third-party ads in your app. When we hear back from you, we will continue the review.
```

But my app presents a `google adBanner` as soon as they game is launched. Even if you somehow press the start button before the Ad is loaded, it still presents itself during the game...

Is there any reason they wouldn't see the AdBanner?

I have my own `adUnitID` and it displays an Ad on my iPhone 6+ device and also the 4S simulator...

Also, I ticked the "servers advertisements within app" check box before submitting:

[image: apple ads]

I've replied saying:

```
Hello.
Please see screenshot of a Google AdBanner... It should show upon launch of the game.
Steps:
-Open App
-An Ad should load within seconds.

Please advise. Thanks.
```

and attached a screenshot, showing it...

I've done it the same way I have in my last app which is live and serving ads.

This is how I load and serve the ad in the `gameViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-blahblahblah/1010101"

    googleBannerView.rootViewController = self
    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

    googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height -googleBannerView.frame.size.height, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)

    self.view.addSubview(googleBannerView!)

    //more stuff

}
```

Is there anything else I can do to check in the code that it's definitely serving ads? I can't see anything wrong with it.

I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be serving their end...

Also, if it's still in review, do I have to wait another week?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not about programming, but about the App Store review process.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata rejected in `itunesconnect` means 1) that something wrong with app metadata (*description, screenshots, etc.*) **or** 2) Something wrong with things that are serving your app (*backend, some authorization, etc.*). Also it means that you can resubmit your app without uploading new app binary file. Seems like the second case is yours, and the app review team thinks that something went wrong with you ad serving or ad banner in the place that they couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this rejection when they couldn't find my third party ad, Admob, in my app. This was because I was using admob just for interstitial and I used iAd for banners. I had to tell them how and where to get those admob ads to show.

you can try `googleBannerView.hidden = false` (this is the default value) and see if there's a difference

But for your case, since you're using admob banners that should have shown in the first place and you were able to make it show on your test, the only reason I could think of why they did not find it is because of no ad inventory from Admob (I stated this reason as well when I replied) which is rare but still happens.

It will stay in review/rejected state until you fix it by uploading a new binary and resubmitting (which would take the normal week submission and reviewing) or when they are convinced that there is a third party ad network used (from replying and stating your case) which they'll change the app status to 'ready for sale' or approved. Mine took 2 days I think.